# Some queries don't work with dismax solr

Tags: solr, field, dismax

I use solr and dismax reqest handler.

But when I use this handler, some queries as query by field haven't worked.

What's the problem ?

Thanks

Comment: add one example query to your question

Answer (score 0):

For ex, when using standard Lucene query parser, you use:

```
http://whatever:8280/solr/fr_00/select?q=cat:7030100&wt=json&indent=true
```

But when using dismax, you have to use something like:

```
http://whatever:8280/solr/fr_00/select?q=7030100&qf=cat&wt=json&indent=true&defType=dismax
```

this should also work

```
&fq=cat:(7030100)
```